# Getting Error 400 while requesting from tensorflow_serving on docker

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, python-requests, tensorflow-serving

I created a model and deployed it using tensorflow_serving on docker. Now when im REQUEST.POST, it is returning Error 400.

Deployed by:

```
 docker run -p 8501:8501 --name my_model_1 --mount type=bind,source="/Users/subhamsingh/Desktop/rztdl/samples/experiments/tf_serving_tests/saves/",target=/models/my_model -e MODEL_NAME=my_model -t tensorflow/serving
```

Request structure:

```
dd = []
for i in range(784):
  dd.append(i)
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": dd})
print(dd)
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
```

json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model:predict', data=data, headers=headers)

The model is deployed on docker on my local and request is being sent from my local to my docker in the local sys.

How do i resolve/debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
Actually the shape that I'm passing is wrong.
It should actually be(same as while on training):

```
dd = [dd]
```